# How to get value from Parent Gridview using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get the ID from the parent Gridview using link button in my nested Gridview but i get different ID every-time i click the link.  For example, if i click the link ID for 25 i get the values for ID 24, or if i click the link for ID #18 then i get the values for ID#17 and so forth... so it is always minus one.  so how how can i increment my row ID like if i have row.Cells[0] i want to show row.Cells[0] + 1 something like this.  I just need some kind of solution so please help.  here is my code:

```
 protected void Edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent)
        {

            string myvar = row.Cells[0].Text;

            sqlcon.Open();
            sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select ID, Name, Location where ID = '" + myvar + "' ", sqlcon);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            sqlcon.Close();
            DV_Edit.DataSource = dt;
            DV_Edit.DataBind();
            sqlcon.Close();

            popup.Show();
        }
}
```

i am adding a rows that are used for searching above the headers of my Gridview and i believe that is why i am getting mismatch.  Here is the code that adds the rows:

```
   protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        for (int i = 0; i < GV_EditProject.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
            txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = GV_EditProject.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            txtSearch.CssClass = "search_textbox";
            cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
        }
        GV_EditProject.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
    using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent)
    {
        Integer idx = row.RowIndex + 1;
        if (idx < gridView1.Rows.Count) {
            GridViewRow theRow = gridView1.Rows[idx];
            //string myvar = row.Cells[0].Text;
            string myvar = theRow.Cells[0].Text;
        }
```

Comment: Jumpei, your solution works.. but only when i have more than one row in the parent gridview, meaning if i have 2,3 or more rows it works fine but when i have only one row then it does not work and i get this error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" Please help i am almost there. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try NamingContainer property.

```
using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer)
{

   string myvar = row.Cells[0].Text;

}
```

Comment: Unnie, I have tried this but did not work.  I have updated my initial post please look at it.  I am adding an empty rows on the fly and these rows are used for searching purpose in the gridview.  maybe that is why i am having these issues.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should include the DataKeyNames in your definition of the GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" ... />
```

Then in the codebehind you can retrieve it:

```
using (GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((LinkButton)sender).Parent.Parent)
{

    string myvar = gridview1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].ToString();

   ...
}
```

Comment: Rick, i have included the datakey in my gridview but i am using slightly different than your proposed solution.  I am using Gridview parent to access the ID, how can i modify my code in order to use the datakey?  thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer.  However, I'm not sure your solution for getting the row is 100% correct.  Give it go and see what happens.

Comment: What do you mean, it did not work?  You get an error?  Wrong Id?

Comment: Rick, i have updated my code so please look at my initial post.  I think i am adding rows above the header and these rows are used for searching the gridview and i think that is why i am getting the mismatch please see my initial post.  thanks